# word choice to reply - RSVP

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

So I got an invitation to go to a free dancing class . I want to answer my teacher that I will be able to attend the training. What is the best way to word this ? Here's what I came up with, but it does not sound like a native speaker, to me.

" Hi Ms. Gale,

So, I am able to clear up my schedule this weekend, and I would love to go join  the training session with you. "

How would you say it ? I feel like I always have this "**so..**" in front of everything I say, but I would like to break this habit and be able to use like something else.

Comment: "How would you say this?", "What is the best way to word this?", and similar questions are too broad or primarily-opinion based  and are generally not welcome on ELL. But if you can [edit] your post and address one or two specific issues, then it should be ok. One specific issue you have addressed is the usage of "so"? Do you have another specific issue?

Comment: Hi @Max  I see.... where would you recommend me to post this type of question. Please recommend.  My goal for this question is to know what would native speaker answer this type of question "RSVP" - so I am asking for " word choice ".  For  "so" , issue that is additional question that I would also like to address.  Now that you mention "Too Board"  .. please recommend me where should I post this type of question. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is [our page](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) for that. Anyway, since your brought it up, you can drop the "so" if you want to break the habit. It's fine. The only other "obvious" problem, per se, is "training session". If it is a training session, then call it that. If it is a dance class, call it that. I don't see a problem with simply "class" if you both understand which class it is.

Comment: To make it more upbeat, you could start with "Fortunately I *was* able to...". *clearing you schedule* has already been accomplished at the time of your message, so this should be in the past tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring anything else just dump the "so" and start straight in with "I am able to…"

This is always true when "So" is used as the strange modern idiom… it sounds less unattractive than "Er…" or "Um…" but it has no more meaning and less place…